# Google Drive Account Picker onActivityResult resultCode is always -1

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am currently working on an android application and I am trying to integrate Google Drive. I'm having a problem with the account picker, that when the account is chosen and it returns into the onActivityResult function the resultCode is -1 which I believe it should be 0 to mean that it was successful.

Below is how I am opening the account picker

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER
```

`credential` is a global variable so the whole class has access to this variable.

Below is the code for the onActivityResult

```
else if (resultCode == REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null)
    {
    String accountName = intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("google_drive_account_name", accountName);
    editor.putBoolean("drive_sync_upload_download_required", true);
    editor.commit();
    }
}
```

It goes into the else if statement fine but when it checks if the resultCode equals RESULT_OK it returns false as the resultCode is for some reason being set to -1. I assume -1 means that something has failed but I can't see any error messages in the logCat.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you able to solve the issue? As i am also getting 0 in resultCode. not sure what's wrong with authentication.

Comment: I mean i am getting 0 means cancelled so do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Oh sorry, not sure, the only way I know this would happen is if you call setResult(0) or setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED). If you're not doing that then your best bet is to ask your own question and provide code for others to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK): value of `RESULT_OK` is `-1`.

`0` is for `RESULT_CANCELLED`

Comment: Thanks for the help, seems a bit of an odd way of doing it, 0 usually means success in everything else I've worked on. Thanks for the help though